# MySQL - Is it possible to pick a value from a field as an table for "from" or "join" queries?

Tags: mysql

### Background

Because its not possible to define a "unknown" or dynamic relation in sql ( `List<Object>` instead of `List<Item>` for example ), i hacked a bit to simulate such relations...

```
Table Structure
Entity | Id, otherReferences
Inventory | Id, item_Entity_Id

Example
Entity | 1 | "inventory"
```

that string "inventory" means that entity 1 has a 1:1 relation to inventory 1

Why ? Because i dont know the table or type of the 1:1 relation, its for one of my games and that assoziation is pretty dynamic.

If i want to join both, i would simply construct a query in my game that looks like this, i basically just take the `entity.otherReferences` value and place it into the `join ... on` for constructing a query.

```sql
select * from entity inner join inventory on inventory.id = entity.id
```

### Question

Is it somehow possible to define some sort of dynamic/automatic sql query that takes the "join ... on" table value from a field ? Basically what my program does, some sort of query constructor, but as a native sql query ?

Any help appreciated, thanks !

Comment: There's no way to do it in ordinary SQL. You can do it by creating the query dynamically with `PREPARE` in a stored procedure or a client programming language.

Comment: In general, SQL isn't designed to handle queries where table and/or column names are determined dynamically. Dynamic information should be in table contents, not table and column names.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your fast answer ! Damn... thats a pitty, i also considered using nosql, but my game is pretty relation heavy. Im gonna look into prepare's, besides that... do you have any idea in mind how i could model a 1:1/1:n relation without knowing what table my target is ( List<Object> ) ? ^^

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the JSON datatype, but maybe that would be useful for you.